# How to create a JS object with dynamic values without reinitializing it?

Tags: javascript, object

How should I define functions `makeDynamicConfig` and `dynamicConfigValue` so that after running the code below the value of `object_new` would be

```
{
  "key": "new:key",
  "key2": "new:key2"
}
```

The code:

```
let currentConfig = 'initial'

const changeConfig = (config) => {
    currentConfig = config;
}

const object = makeDynamicConfig({
    key: dynamicConfigValue('key'),
    key2: dynamicConfigValue('key2'),
});

changeConfig('new');
const object_new = JSON.stringify(object);
```

I can't come up with the solution without initializing the object every time after changing the `currentConfig` state.

With the provided code after run the value of `object_new` is

```
{
  "key": "initial:key",
  "key2": "initial:key2"
}
```

instead of

```
{
  "key": "new:key",
  "key2": "new:key2"
}
```

Comment: What does `'test'` or `'new'` have to do with the result you expect? Where should `'ru'` come from?

Comment: I think this will require creating a `Proxy` object in `dynamicConfigValue()`, but this is something I've never gotten experience with.

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry, edit the question. In the result value of `currentConfig` should be added to `key`.

Comment: Why do you do `changeConfig('new');` and not just `currentConfig = 'new'`? Seems overkill to define a function for setting a variable that is just as global as the function.

Comment: What would be expected from `makeDynamicConfig`? I don't see why it is needed.

Comment: @trincot you're right! Still, the problem remains unsolved

Comment: What is the problem? Concatenating two strings?

Comment: @trincot I expect from `makeDynamicConfig` to somehow make the provided object "dynamic" so it would update its key values when the value of `currentConfig` is updated

Comment: `object` doesn't look syntactically correct. `const object = {...}` is an object literal. If `makeDynamicConfig()` is a function, then post it's definition. ex. `function makeDynamicConfig() {...}`

Comment: I think your example code should be extended so it makes two outputs; and add the expected output for each, to illustrate what you mean with "dynamic" here.

Comment: @trincot I've updated the question with current output and expected output

Comment: Too bad, the update is not clearing out what you want (I think I get it). The question has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get the output you want with the information you've given, you don't really need to do a whole lot.  I don't think you'll need a `makeDynamicConfig` function at all.

```js
let currentConfig = 'initial'

const changeConfig = (config) => {
    currentConfig = config;
}

const dynamicConfigValue = (input) => {
  return currentConfig + ':' + input;
}

changeConfig('new');

const object = {
    key: dynamicConfigValue('key'),
    key2: dynamicConfigValue('key2'),
};

console.log(object)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edit the question. I accidentally put the "ru" instead of an updated `currentConfig` value.

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to reflect this.  I mean it's pretty basic, you are just adding strings together.  If this is what helps you please mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Based on Barmar's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103792/how-to-create-a-js-object-with-dynamic-values-without-reinitializing-it#comment134215526_76103792) under the question I've come up with this.
Maybe this is what you were trying to achieve?

```js
let currentConfig = "initial";
const changeConfig = (config) => {
    currentConfig = config;
}
const dynamicConfHandler = {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
        return `${currentConfig}:${target[prop]}`;
    },
};
const makeDynamicConfig = (obj) => {
    return new Proxy(obj, dynamicConfHandler);
};

const object = makeDynamicConfig({
    key: "value",
    key2: "value2",
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(object)); // will print {initial:value, initial:value2}"

changeConfig('new');
const object_new = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(object_new); // will print "{new:value, new:value2}"
```

Documentation for the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) class used here.

The `dynamicConfigValue` method you requested is the handler method given to the proxy.